# accessor considered as foreign key defined in OneToMany relations

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.5

My `User` model have these fields :

```
user_id
username
name
family
supervisor
```

And in that model I defined an accesssor that same name as supervisor attribute like this (because I want to return supervisor user as an User object and not a simple id):

```
public function getSupervisorAttribute($value)
{
    return is_null($value) ? null : User::select('user_id', 'name', 'family')->find($value);
}
```

In the other hand there is a **OneToMany** relationship like this:

```
public function child()
{
    return $this->hasMany(self::class, 'supervisor', 'user_id');
}
```

Now each time I call **child()** relation it return `Illegal offset type` error. seems that `supervisor` field does not recognized in second argument of **hasMany** method.

There is any way to solve this problem Without having to change accessor name.

Comment: can you show the logs?

Comment: as i know when use hasMany method , return value is collection ... but i think you behave it like model

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem comes when you try to retrieve the relationship child, why? Because you have an accessor on your `supervisor` which is a foreign key inside of `child` relationship, so what happens is when you ask for that relationship, `Laravel` will try to use your supervisor property, since it has an accessor, it will trigger and instead of getting a desired property (which i guess is an integer), you will either get `NULL` or a `User`. I hope this clarifies it for you.

One workaround for this is to add `appends` attribute to your `Model` and then put mutators and accessors on that attribute.

Answer (score 0):

If a `User` has children then it's one to many(he/she can have many children or none)

Anyway,
Lets assume you have a table named `Children` make sure you change the table name in the model(laravel assumes it's childrens in the DB).

If `public function child() {}` is in the `User` model then,

```
/* 
 * children since he/she can have many children
 * hasMany means this model has many of the other model by self::class
 * it's as if you're saying this model has many of this model so change it 
 */
public function children()
{
    /* you're building a relationship between User('user_id' as local primary key) 
     * and Children('parent_id' as foreign key) 
     * means children table has foreign key parent_id(unsignedInt)
     * it returns an array of all the children objects of this User row
     */
    return $this->hasMany('Children', 'parent_id', 'user_id');
}
```

On the other hand the `Children` Model:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Children extends Model
{
    /**
     * The table associated with the model.
     *
     * @var string
     */
     protected $table = 'children';

     public function parent()
     {
         // belongsTo means 'parent_id' in this model(Children) relates to 'user_id' on 'User' model
         // it returns the User object which is the parent of this child row
         return $this->belongsTo('User', 'user_id', 'parent_id');
     }
}
```

This solution is for creating another table however it seems you want it with the same table(it's not very clear edit your post).

```
// this function makes no sense, it takes an integer and finds the parameter to was given
$userWithIdOne = $user->getSupervisorAttribute(1);
```

**Give us the migrations of the table, show us the relationships.**